# Unreliable file system operations on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, file-io, filesystems

I had to notice some strange behaviour of [Bazaar](http://bazaar.canonical.com)'s directory locking mechanism on my machine and tried to reproduce that. Here's my simple testcase:

1. Create a directory `Test`, then `Test/held`, then a file `Test/held/info`.
2. Rename `Test` to `YXCV`.
3. Read the file created in step 1 (now from the path `YXCV/held/info`).
4. Clean up (remove the file and the directories).
5. Repeat.

Strange enough, this fails. Sometimes in step 2 ("Permission denied"), sometimes in step 3 (file could not be opened, although I can open the file in a regular text editor afterwards). *Sometimes this fails immediately, sometimes several thousand iterations are performed succesfully*.

I'm running Windows 7 here. I suspect some configuration changes (corporate IT administration out of my control), because the problem occured just a week ago.

Do you know any possible plausible explanation?

This is my test code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#include <direct.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void mkdir() {
    if ( mkdir( "Test" ) ) throw std::runtime_error( "mkdir" );
    if ( mkdir( "Test/held" ) ) throw std::runtime_error( "mkdir" );
}

void create() {
    if ( !std::ofstream( "Test/held/info" ).write( "asdf", 4 ) )
        throw std::runtime_error( "create" );
}

void rename() {
    if ( rename( "Test", "YXCV" ) ) throw std::runtime_error( "rename" );
}

void peek() {
    char buf[ 4 ];
    if ( !std::ifstream( "YXCV/held/info" ).read( buf, 4 ) )
        throw std::runtime_error( "peek" );
}

void del() {
    if ( unlink( "YXCV/held/info" ) ) throw std::runtime_error( "remove" );
    if ( rmdir( "YXCV/held" ) ) throw std::runtime_error( "remove" );
    if ( rmdir( "YXCV" ) ) throw std::runtime_error( "remove" );
}

void cleanup() {
    unlink( "Test/held/info" );
    rmdir( "Test/held" );
    rmdir( "Test" );
    unlink( "YXCV/held/info" );
    rmdir( "YXCV/held" );
    rmdir( "YXCV" );
}

int main() {
    cleanup();
    int count = 1;
    try {
        for ( ;; ++count ) {
            mkdir ();
            create();
            rename();
            peek  ();
            del   ();
        }
    }
    catch ( const std::exception &e ) {
        std::cout << "Run: " << count << "\nError: " << e.what() << "\n\t"
                  << strerror( errno ) << '\n';
    }
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: You can use [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) to figure out exactly the failed operation and the error code. Maybe you getting sharing violation.

Comment: check if peek() method has any open handles to the "info" file

Comment: Try it with any anti-virus programs you have shutdown.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Definitely worth a try. If that's a possible effect of anti-virus software I wonder how my system keeps usable anyway.

Answer (score 1):

When I run your programme alone it loops forever without error.

However, once I perform some filesystem operations concurrently, using other programs,  your code fails exactly as you've described:

- if open an explorer windows and navigate in the leaf directory that are created and stay there, your code fails to delete or to rename the directories (step 1 or 4).
- if I open the new file with some text editor, the reading of the file fails (step 3).

This is normal behaviour on the windows filesystem.  For example, if a programme has a handle on a directory, this one can't be removed ([`rmdir()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wt8es881.aspx) error code `EACCESS`).

You've explained that you're working within a Bazaar version management directory structure.  This means that some background service processes monitor changes in the directories and files, and eventually execute some [hooks and plugins](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/bzr.2.6/en/admin-guide/hooks-plugins.html) (which could prolong the locking conditions). This typically will create the locking situations described above.

***P.S:*** To help you see what's going on, you may use Microsoft's [process explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) and search for the file handle  with <kbd>Ctrl+F</kbd>. Enter the name of the file in the field "handle", and it will show you which processes use the file.  Attention:  run as administrator is required to search also system processes.

Comment: In most cases you can work around the problem by explicitly verifying that the directory no longer exists after removing it, and if not, retrying the remove operation periodically.  It should also be noted that Windows is not designed to support using the directory structure as a locking mechanism.  Instead, it provides explicit file locking mechanisms.

Comment: I know that windows does not like to remove directories opened in explorer (on local drives, network drives seem to work differently). Opening the text file works fine here. So, if some concurrent (locking) operations take place, I get the *expected* error. But: I've tried to *run it alone*, I even turned off Bazaar's background process.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Perhaps I should not have mentioned "Bazaar" and "locking", as I'm interested in possible reasons why the above access pattern could fail. But yes, if used as a locking mechanism failure because of concurrent operations is expected and intended.

Comment: Thing is though that you can't really control all possible concurrent operations.  There's anti-virus, there's Windows Search, any number of third-party programs, and I don't know what else.  I suspect you'll find that the problem disappears if you put the `rmdir` calls in a loop, i.e., make the cleanup() function synchronous.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Ok, learned something about Windows: `rmdir` calls `RemoveDirectory` internally, and that just "marks a directory for deletion on close", making that function asynchronous. Thus I don't have to loop over `rmdir`, I just have to wait for the deletion to happen. Apparently, `rename` (which calls `MoveFileEx`) does as well, perhaps due to the same reason, although I can't see that clearly stated in [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365240%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Yes, in your context that would probably work.  (If you're deleting a directory tree with a single command, the operation can fail and hence need to be retried.  But you're deleting individual items one at a time, so if you wait for each one to complete, I guess you'll be OK.)  I don't *think* that `MoveFileEx` is asynchronous, it is probably just failing because of the race condition with the directory operations.  (I could be wrong.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston very interesting !

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting an answer here to show how I worked around that now.

Taking the "open file `YXCV/held/info` issue" as an example, the difference is that I explicitly check the existence of the file (by calling `stat()`) prior to opening it.

Funny thing is: I don't have to retry the `rename()`, this has been successful according to the return code, my function `seek()` just does not see it immediately. All errors I have observed can be worked around by waiting for the file system state expected being observable.

EDIT: As noted in a comment to Christophe's post, `rmdir` calls `RemoveDirectory` internally, and that just "marks a directory for deletion on close", making that function asynchronous. Thus I don't have to loop over rmdir, I just have to wait for the deletion to happen. Apparently, `rename` (which calls `MoveFileEx`) does as well, perhaps due to the same reason, although I can't see that clearly stated [in the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365240%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), so there are still *mysteries to be solved*.

See the full code here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#include <direct.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#include <Windows.h>

bool exists( const char *p ) {
    struct stat buffer;
    return stat( p, &buffer ) == 0;
}

void wait_for( const char *p ) {
    while ( !exists( p ) ) {
        std::cout << "wait for " << p << '\n';
        Sleep( 500 );
    }
}

void wait_for_del( const char *p ) {
    while ( exists( p ) ) {
        std::cout << "wait for deletion of " << p << '\n';
        Sleep( 500 );
    }
}

void mkdir() {
    if ( mkdir( "Test" ) ) throw std::runtime_error( "mkdir" );
    if ( mkdir( "Test/held" ) ) throw std::runtime_error( "mkdir" );
}

void create() {
    if ( !std::ofstream( "Test/held/info" ).write( "asdf", 4 ) )
        throw std::runtime_error( "create" );
}

void rename() {
    wait_for( "Test" );
    if ( rename( "Test", "YXCV" ) ) throw std::runtime_error( "rename" );
}

void peek() {
    wait_for( "YXCV/held/info" );
    char buf[ 4 ];
    if ( !std::ifstream( "YXCV/held/info" ).read( buf, 4 ) )
        throw std::runtime_error( "peek" );
}

void del() {
    wait_for( "YXCV/held/info" );
    if ( unlink( "YXCV/held/info" ) ) throw std::runtime_error( "remove" );
    if ( rmdir( "YXCV/held" ) ) throw std::runtime_error( "remove" );
    if ( rmdir( "YXCV" ) ) throw std::runtime_error( "remove" );
    wait_for_del( "YXCV" );
}

void cleanup() {
    unlink( "Test/held/info" );
    wait_for_del( "Test/held/info" );
    rmdir( "Test/held" );
    wait_for_del( "Test/held" );
    rmdir( "Test" );
    wait_for_del( "Test" );
    unlink( "YXCV/held/info" );
    wait_for_del( "YXCV/held/info" );
    rmdir( "YXCV/held" );
    wait_for_del( "YXCV/held" );
    rmdir( "YXCV" );
    wait_for_del( "YXCV" );
}

int main() {
    cleanup();
    int count = 1;
    try {
        for ( ; count <= 1000; ++count ) {
            mkdir ();
            create();
            rename();
            peek  ();
            del   ();
        }
        std::cout << "OK.";
    }
    catch ( const std::exception &e ) {
        std::cout << "Run: " << count << "\nError: " << e.what() << "\n\t"
                  << strerror( errno ) << '\n';
    }
    std::cin.get();
}
```